# Localhost & local IP 80 port not working - connection failed in client PC

Tags: telnet

While giving telnet command for localhost & local IP 80 port not working and connection failed in client PC.  In the same pc I am able to connect outside server ( where our system's application server Oracle 11g is located) with telnt 80 port.

To reach the outside server I have to go through local IP.  since the local IP is not connecting to the port 80 in telnet I am not able to access the server. but the same local IP works in other client PCs. I hope this is a local client issue.

Kindly guide what kind of components to be invoked to access port 80 in local client PC? what are all the Firewall, windows components settings & services is required?This client PC recovered recently from Crash & factory default settings was restored . The O/S is Vista. Before the system crash everything was fine.

Answer (score 2):

In order to connect to port 80 on the local machine you need to have a service running on that local machine to accept connections.  For port 80, that service is typically a web server.  So you would need a web server(something like [Apache](http://apache.org)) which is accepting connections on port 80 in order to achieve what you are asking.  What is it you are trying to accomplish?